# Get only metadata info about a particular column without looping through them all.. is it possible?

Tags: java, jdbc

is there an alternative to looping through all the columns of DatabaseMetaData.getColumns() if I want to find only some info about a column I know the name of?

My guess is no, but since I'm new to JDBC... maybe some of you have some suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at the documentation, it is quite extensive. You can query for a specific column using the fourth parameter `columnNamePattern` of [`getColumns()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

> `columnNamePattern` - a column name pattern; must match the column name as it is stored in the database

This parameter is a `LIKE` pattern, so `"%"` queries all columns, `"someColumn"` queries for `someColumn`. Note that if this column is case insensitive you may need to use `"somecolumn"` or `"SOMECOLUMN"` depending on the way case insensitive names are stored in your database (see also the various `stores*` methods in `DatabaseMetaData`).

Comment: great.. somehow I missed that, I was focusing more on reading the example code on some webpage that looped through everything